# E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-layout

I just started learning Android and I have following error in my first example please help me.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button buttonNesnesi=(Button) findViewById(id.button1);

        buttonNesnesi.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() 
            {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Hello!!!",1000).show();
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{net.developersland/net.developersland.SecondActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

And this is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be,

```
final Button buttonNesnesi=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

not a

```
final Button buttonNesnesi=(Button) findViewById(id.button1);
```

Comment: Thanks that is work!
But why compiler doesn't give any warning or error when I make this mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **R**.id.button1

```
final Button buttonNesnesi=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```